# Distributional derivative of bounded functions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$.  We may consider its derivative $f'$ as a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.

> Is there a reasonable description of those distributions $\psi$ which arise in this way, i.e. are of the form $\psi = f'$ for some bounded measurable $f$?

For instance, $f'$ need not be a measure (it is a measure iff $f$ has bounded variation).  On the other hand, the doublet $\psi = \delta_0'$ is not of this form.

Considering $f \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ would also be interesting.

More generally, on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I would also like to know which distributions are of the form $\psi = \operatorname{div} F$ for $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded and measurable (or $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$).

Comment: This does not answer the question, but seems worth mentioning; a differential form $\omega$ is called *flat* if $\omega\in L^\infty$ and $d\omega\in L^\infty$ (exterior derivative, taken in the distributional sense). These are studied in Whitney's book *Geometric Integration Theory*.

Comment: At least for $\mathbb{R}$, isn't this precisely the Sobolev space $W^{1,\infty}$? And the elements of this space are the bounded Lipschitz continuous functions.

Comment: @Vobo That happens if you *integrate* an $L^{\infty}$ function. Differentiation moves you in the opposite direction: from $L^{\infty}=W^{0,\infty}$ you get to $W^{-1,\infty}$. Which is the dual of $W^{1,1}$, but I'm not sure that Nate would accept this as a *reasonable description*.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as user31373 wrote, the space would be $W^{-1,\infty}=(W^{1,1})'$.
It contains some measures, but also distributions $f$ of order $1$, so distribution that are not measures, as you point out, but that only need $\varphi$ to be derivable to have $\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ well defined. One can think of them as functions such that, when you do a convolution with them, you get an unbounded operator
$$
T : φ ↦ f*\varphi.
$$
Take for example $\sin(1/x^n)$. Then its derivative is $-n\,\cos(1/x^n)/x^{n+1}$, to be interpreted as a principal value (as for the distribution $1/x$):
$$
\left\langle\tfrac{\cos(1/x^n)}{x^{n+1}},\varphi\right\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\tfrac{\cos(1/x^n)}{x^{n+1}} (\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\,\mathrm{d} x
$$
This is really singular, but still a distribution of order one, because oscillating a lot. So either your are the derivative of a function in $BV\cap L^\infty$, and then you are a measure, either your are a derivative a function of unbounded variations ...