# When is the distributional derivative a function?

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $u \in D'(\mathbb{R})$  be a distribution and suppose that its distributional derivative $u'$ can be identified with an $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ function. Can the distribution $u$ itself then also be identified with an $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ function?

Stated differently, if $u$ is a distribution which is not a function, can its distributional derivative be a function?

Comment: Yes; in fact, $u$ can be identified with an absolutely continuous function...

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting, thanks for the reply. I think I actually know how to prove this now that you mention absolute continuity.

Comment: @NateEldredge Very interesting! If you happen to find a proof of this I would be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Never mind, that's wrong: if $u$ has locally unbounded variation then its derivative is not a measure.  I apparently [knew this 8 years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157430/distributional-derivative-of-bounded-functions).

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the effort anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $u$ can be identified with an absolutely continuous function.

Let $v(x) = \int_0^x u'(y)\,dy$, where the integral makes sense when we treat $u'$ as a locally integrable function.  Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus for Lebesgue integrals, $v$ is absolutely continuous and $v' = u'$ almost everywhere.  Since $v'$ is also the distributional derivative of $v$, we have that the distribution $u-v$ satisfies $(u-v)'=0$.  This implies that $u-v$ is some constant $c$, so we have $u=v+c$ as distributions.